# Array sorting question

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I have an array such as this one:

```
Array
(
    [-1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 3
            [1] => 1
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 7
            [5] => 5
        )
)
```

**It also contains some other keys that should not be modified.**

I'd like to the numbers which are in a second array to come first (in the order of that second array), and then will be the numbers that don't exist in the second array, if any.

So for that matter, the second array would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 3
)
```

And the final array should be as follows (**please remember, there are some more keys inside of that array that should stay as they are**):

```
Array
(
    [-1] => Array
        (
            [6] => 6
            [5] => 5
            [3] => 3
            [1] => 1
            [7] => 7
        )
)
```

Any ideas how that can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look like an array. Nor like a sorting...

Comment: Array, yes.  PHP arrays are actually ordered maps.  But i don't see the logic behind the "sorting".  I have a feeling the word is being misused here.

Comment: Well, in summary, I need the numbers from the second array to be first (by order), then the numbers that don't exist in the second array, if any.

Comment: I think that you should have used the term `permutation` and not `sorting`.

Comment: You want to permute the first array according to the second (that defines the partial permutation) and push what's left of the first array to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not and shouldn't be termed as sorting but may be this code snippet may help you do what you want to:

```
         $a1 = Array ( [-1] => Array ( [3] => 3 [1] => 1 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [5] => 5 ) );
            $a2 = Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 );
            $sorted = getSortedArray($a1[-1] , $array2);
                function getSortedArray($array1 , $array2){
                 $temp = Array();
                 $count = 0;
                 $totalKeys = sizeof($array2);
                 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array2);$i++){


 $temp[i] = $array1[$array2[i]];      
unset($array1[$array2[i]]);
    }
                 while($count!=sizeof($array1))
                          $temp[$totalKeys++] = $array1[$count++];                      
        return $temp;   



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function you're looking for is called [array_multisort()](http://us.php.net/array_multisort).

> array_multisort() can be used to sort
>   several arrays at once, or a
>   multi-dimensional array by one or more
>   dimensions.